# Does changing the Google Cloud project network service tier change running services or only apply to new things?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

Does changing the network service tier for a project in Google Cloud change or otherwise interrupt existing, running network services such as load balancers and compute engine VMs or does it only apply to new things?

Documentation suggests the latter, but we don't want to mess with this setting without getting a definitive answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Does changing the network service tier for a project in Google Cloud
> change or otherwise interrupt existing, running network services such
> as load balancers and compute engine VMs?

Existing services will not be interrupted.

The network service tier affects how traffic is routed from the client into the Google Cloud Network. Premium Tier means that clients will connect to the closest entry point (POP) into Google's network.

This does not directly affect services but does affect routing and latency of traffic to services. I am not aware of any direct impact on your services in the cloud except for the pricing of network traffic.

If Premium Tier is not enabled some features are not available such as global IP addresses.

Always configure Premium Tier. There are no solid technical reasons to select Standard Tier.